# Reverse way in "which $skip/skip()" returns elements

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am performing an aggregate query where I want to select a single document that contains an array of documents which I then filter out based a condition. I want to implement a paging system so I am relying on the `$skip` operator.

The issue is that even after ordering my documents `$skip` will start from the *first* documents and instead I want the documents to be skipped starting from the end.

```
myCollection.aggregate( {$match : {title : title, available : true} }, 
                        {$unwind : '$versions'},
                         {$match : {'versions.active' : true } }
        ,               {$sort : {'versions.dateAdded' : 1}},
                         {$skip : offset},
                        {$limit : 10} );
```

where `offset` is a value I would calculate.

Say I have the query selects the document

```
{
  title : 'ab',
  available : true,
  versions : [{name : 'v1', active : true, dateAdded: ISODATE...},
              {name : 'v2', active : true, dateAdded: ISODATE...},
              {name : 'v3', active : true, dateAdded: ISODATE...},
              {name : 'v4', active : true, dateAdded: ISODATE...},
              {name : 'v5', active : true, dateAdded: ISODATE...}]
}
```

I want the `$skip` operator to start from the last array element. I thought a possible solution might be to return the number of elements that were selected from the `{$match : {'versions.active' : true}}` and then subtracting the offset, I tried the `$size` operator but that just returns the full size of the array and that only those elements that satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm presuming because your sort does not contain any other keys that "title" is unique here, and this seems to be the case if "skip/limit" works for you basically here. Therefore, just "reverse" the sort order:

```js
myCollection.aggregate([
     {$match : {title : title, available : true} }, 
     {$unwind : '$versions'},
     {$match : {'versions.active' : true } }
     {$sort : {'versions.dateAdded' : -1}},
     {$skip : offset},
     {$limit : 10},
     {$sort : {'versions.dateAdded' : 1}}
])
```

And that means going "backwards" through the list, and then the last `$sort` re-orders the list after the "skip/limit".